# Numbering or counting the appended lines in python

Tags: python, function, file, for-loop, count

I would like to count or add numbers to the file everytime I add something to it.

My file is consist of

```
 Account|Username|Password
```

I would like to have it like this whenever the user adds another account.

```
 #  Account  Username  Password
 1  Facebook  Name    Pass
```

My code of adding account is this

```
def add_account():
    acc = input("Enter the name of your account.")
    username = input(f"Enter the username of your {acc}")
    password = input(f"Enter the password of your {acc}")
    ask = input(f" Do you like to save {acc} credentials? Y|N")

    if ask == "Y":
        with open("myfile.txt", "a") as file:
             file.write("" + "|" + acc + "|" + username + "|" + password)
             file.close()

add_accout()

def view_account():
    file = open("myfile.txt", "r")
    line = file.readline()
      for line in file:
          a, b, c, d = line.split("|")
          d = d.strip()
          print(formatStr(a), formatStr(b), formatStr(c), formatStr(d))

view_account()

def formatStr(str):
     nochars = 15
     return str + (" "*(nochars - len(str))
```

How can I count the appended lines?

Comment: Is that your entire program (which adds at most one account before it exits)? Os is there more to it?

Comment: It's not the entire program. It's just part of if. I'm having trouble with it.

Comment: If your goal is to report how many accounts were added while the program was running then keep a global count and increment it each time you add an account.

Comment: Can you try showing me a code? I don't really get it, sorry.

Comment: Ah, re-reading your question, I see that you actually want to number the accounts in the actual file, so you need to know the last-added number to be able to write the next account. First thing I would say is: don't do this, if you don't have to. The index of each account in the file is implicitly known (because account N is at line N+1).

Comment: If you must write account numbers, then read the entire file using readlines() and parse the last line for the account number.

Comment: I think I got it, thank you too!

Comment: You've shown 2 different formats for the content of myfile.txt. One is pipe (|) separated while the other is whitespace-separated (and also contains a row number). Your code to write the file itself introduces a 3rd, different format (and this code is bugged).

Comment: I've already edited it, thank you. But I still can't get it work. It always remain "1" when I tried to add another account. Oh, I need to re-run it first before adding another account, maybe that's the reason why it still stays at "1"? But how can I count it without using list or tuples?

Comment: OK, so you've modified the code to write a pipe separator to your DB (myfile.txt) and you now need to add the next account number (because at present, the code is writing an empty string for the account number). Is the restriction simply that you must not use the keyword `list` or is it that you must not use lists, even indirectly (for example str.split() returns a list, are you allowed to use that?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to be able to quit the program, restart it later, and have it discover the last account number stored in your database, then you can do this as follows to calculate the next free account number:

```
SEPARATOR = '|'

def next_account_number():
    next_num = 1

    with open("myfile.txt", "r") as f:
        # Read lines discarding empty lines
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
        lines = list(filter(lambda x: x != "", lines))

        if len(lines) > 1:
            account = lines[-1].split(SEPARATOR)

            try:
                next_num = int(account[0]) + 1
            except ValueError:
                pass

    return next_num


print("Next account number:", next_account_number())
```

Comment: Is there another way without using list?

Comment: Do you have some artificial restriction that means you're unable to use `list` in your solution? What exactly is the restriction?

Comment: We're not allowed to use list or tuples.

Answer (score 1):

As jarmod is suggesting in the comments, you can use a global counting variable to number each added account:

```
counting = 0
                   
def add_account():
    global counting
    acc = input("Enter the name of your account.")
    username = input(f"Enter the username of your {acc}")
    password = input(f"Enter the password of your {acc}")
    ask = input(f" Do you like to save {acc} credentials? Y|N")

    if ask == "Y":
        counting += 1
        with open("myfile.txt", "a") as file:
            file.write("" + acc + username + password + str(counting))
            file.close()

add_account()
```

Comment: I've tried it but the count is always "1".I did what you've told me but the count always come out to be "1".

Comment: You need to make sure you define the function and initialize the counting variable once. Then you only call the function `add_account()`, without redefining the global counting variable every time. Otherwise it will restart from 0 every time.

Comment: Oh, okay! Thank you so much!